# Finding the limit of $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{x}{{\ln (5x + 1)}}$

Tags: calculus, limits, functions

$$\lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{x}{\ln (5x + 1)}  = {1 \over 5}$$

First, What I tried to do is dividing by $x$, but it didn't work out.
By the way, It's a common approach to find a limit. Why is it failing here?

Second, I played with the logarithm rules which only brought me to:
$$\log _{5x + 1} e^x = x \log_{5x + 1} e$$

It might be a starter, but I don't know what to do from this point.

Comment: Please notice my edits to your question.  An expression like \mathop{lim}\limits_{x \to {0^+}} is an abominable way of writing MathJax or TeX code.  I changed it to \lim_{x \to 0^+}.  I also deleted some superfluous curly braces.  Those can make editing harder.

Comment: You should know that $\lim \limits_{y\to 0^+}\left(\dfrac{\log (y+1)}{y}\right)=1$.

**Hint:** $\lim \limits_{x\to 0^+}\left(\dfrac x{\log(5x+1)}\right)=\dfrac 1 5\lim \limits_{x\to 0^+}\left(\dfrac {5x}{\log(5x+1)}\right)$.

Comment: @GitGud I'd accept your solution if you wrote it as an answer. The reason is I cannot use l'hospital rule. I should have mentioned it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since both denominator and numerator approaches 0 at the limit of $x\rightarrow 0^+$, you can use the [l'hospital rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule) to find this limit

Answer (score 3):

Use **L'Hospital's  Rule**

For indeterminate forms, like what you have $$\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{x}{\ln(5x+1)} = \frac{0}{0}$$ And given that $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}, \space f'(x) \space g'(x)$ exists.

L'Hospital's Rule says:
$$\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{x}{\ln(5x+1)}= \lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{(x)'}{(\ln(5x+1))'}=...$$

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at L'Hopital's rule. When the numerator and denominator both go to 0 or infinity, you can take the derivative of both and then try finding the limit again.

Here's a good reference: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PdSzruR5OeE

Answer (score 1):

Or using the fact that $\ln(1+t)\sim_0t$, for $t=5x$.